# Many Errors with cocos2d-x-3.0 project creation

Tags: cocos2d-x

So I'm trying to setup a project using cocos2d-x-3.0. I can set everything up just fine, and then import and run my new project in Eclipse with no problems; however, once I open the `main.cpp` file for the first time, a bunch of errors pop up and I can no longer compile my project. The error it gives me is `Unresolved inclusion: AppDelegate.h` on the `#include "AppDelegate.h"`

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "cocos2d.h"
#include "CCEventType.h"
#include "platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "main"
#define  LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

using namespace cocos2d;

void cocos_android_app_init (struct android_app* app) {
    LOGD("cocos_android_app_init");
    AppDelegate *pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();
}
```

I then looked and noticed the `Classes` folder in my project was empty, despite there being classes in the `Classes` folder in the project. So I went and added a new `Class` folder with a link to the auto generated Classes folder in the project folder. This fixes the problem again, but if I open any of the files in my new `Class` folder, it highlights a TON of could not be resolved errors, and I can no longer compile. Here is part of my AppDelegate.h file:

```
#ifndef  _APP_DELEGATE_H_
#define  _APP_DELEGATE_H_

#include "cocos2d.h"

/**
@brief    The cocos2d Application.

The reason for implement as private inheritance is to hide some interface call by Director.
*/
class  AppDelegate : private cocos2d::Application
{
```

There is an error at the `cocos2d::Application` part saying `Symbol 'Application' could not be resolved`.

EDIT:
After remaking the project, I discovered that the `Classes` folder is automatically marked as deprecated in Eclipse. I was able to make a new (non-linked) `Class` folder, and manually add the pre-made classes, and no longer was given any errors. I have no idea why this is, but it worked.

Scratch that, now I only get errors in one of the four files. In `HelloWorldScene.cpp`:

```
// add a "close" icon to exit the progress. it's an autorelease object
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(  // Says "Invalid arguments" for the create call
                                       "CloseNormal.png",
                                       "CloseSelected.png",
                                       CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this)); // "Symbol'_1' could not be resolved" (What is Symbol_1)?

closeItem->setPosition(Point(origin.x + visibleSize.width - closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 ,
                            origin.y + closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));

// create menu, it's an autorelease object
auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Point::ZERO);
this->addChild(menu, 1);
```

There are a few more `Could not be resolved` and `Invalid arguments` errors in there. What confuses me the most about this, is that everything compiles and runs just fine until I open the files and the errors load.

Comment: When you say it doesn't find the Classes folder by default. Have you verified that the path it's linked to is correct? It may be due to the COCOS2DX path variable is set incorrectly.

Comment: am also getting same erorr. r u solve dthis issue using cocs2d-x 3.0 beta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the movement you should use COCOCS 2d-x2.2 for creating project in cocos2d-x. it is easy and good. Try it.

***One thing more that go to Projectproperty int eclips and codeAnalysis(in C/c++ Gneral) then click on use project setting the the UNMARK the CHECK box of SYantax and Semantics error.
It will remove a lot  of error***

Comment: Sounds harsh but I think this is the only way to cadge Eclipse into submission

Answer (score 0):

Make sure of two things:

1. Import the libcocos2dx under your own project directory, as documented here http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Build_an_Android_Project_with_Eclipse;
2. In your Project - Properties - C/C++ General > Code Analysis, unselect Syntax and Semantic Errors - otherwise you'll see the error and won't be able to build from Eclipse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happens but you can:

1. right-click on you project in Eclipse "**Package Explorer**"
2. click on "**Run C/C++ Code Analysis**"

This will remove the errors so you can build/run your project again.