# Unresolved inclusion: "cocos2d.h" - Cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

when I import the cocos2dx android project in my eclipse I get this warning on my header files

```
    Unresolved inclusion: "cocos2d.h"
```

Why is this? Its actually bugging me. The project compiles and runs correctly but I want that to go away. Can someone tell me how to remove that warning and also I want the intellisense feature for my c++ projects in eclipse. I have that feature for my android stuff but not for c++.

Please guide me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You have to add headers path. Check http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_sd_entries.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add cocos2d-x resource to your Eclipse

- Right click your project and choose **Properties**
- Find **Java Build Path**
- Find **Link Source Browse** under **Source Tab**
- Add **$COCOS2DX-HOME/cocos2dx/platform/android/java/src/** and fill **cocos2dx src** in Folder name

Reference:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Comment: Nope no good in this instance, I'm starting to think there are more versions of Eclipse than users.

Answer (score 1):

If it's Cocos2dx v3.0, the answer above is not correct. Please check my answer at this: [Many Errors with cocos2d-x-3.0 project creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968470/many-errors-with-cocos2d-x-3-0-project-creation)