# Cocos2d-x 3.X build Android "cocos2d.h" file not found

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am using build_native.py to build to Android platform, but it says
"fatal error: fatal error:'cocos2d.h' file not found".
Before this problem it says can't import import module and I set NDK_MODULD_PATH in environment variable to fix it I don't know if this cause this problem.

```
In file included from jni/hellocpp/main.cppIn file included from 

jni/../../Class
es/AppDelegate.cppIn file included from jni/../../Classes/GameOverScene.cpp:1:
::jni/../../Classes/GameOverScene.h1:
:4:10: jni/../../Classes/AppDelegate.hfatal error: :4'cocos2d.h' file not found1
:

In file included from #include "cocos2d.h"
```

this is my Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/external)
$(call import-add-path,$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos)

LOCAL_MODULE := cocos2dcpp_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libcocos2dcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/Adapter.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/ControlLayer.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/GameOverScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/GameRunScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/GameStartScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/SceneManager.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../cocos2d/cocos/physics
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libcocos2d

LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_extension_static

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(call host-path,$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)) -lc++_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,./prebuilt-mk)
```

Comment: what is your NDK_MODULD_PATH variable?

Comment: C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.6\cocos;C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.6\external;C:\Cocos\frameworks;C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.6\extensions;C:\Cocos\frameworks\cocos2d-x-3.6

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, most error comes from wrong Path setting of `NDK_MODULD_PATH`. I once met [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22294354/1820217) when using Cocos2d-x 2.2.6. And I suggest you checking the path of `NDK_MODULE_PATH` again to set it to

```
${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/source;${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt
```

replace ${COCOS2DX_ROOT} to your own path. You can also check this [article](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started), although it is talking about Cocos2d-x 2.x.

Comment: You write this lines in your "Android.mk"file?

Answer (score 0):

I miss this error also when I use cocos2d-x-3.7.My solution is at **jni/Android.mk** set:

> LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2d_lua_static

see more at this [FixBug](http://fixbug.kllmctrl.com/20150730/cocos2d-x3-x-build-android/)